# Print each bookmark of a PDF separately

Tags: pdf, printing, bookmarks, extract

I have a very large (1000 page) PDF which contains about 100, ten page each documents one after the other.
I would like to have them sent to my office printer as individual files so my office printer will print them double sided and staple each one individually.

I'm using Adobe Acrobat X and think the first step is to bookmark the start of each of those 100 documents. I don't know the next step though.

I also have a batch printing program so if i can extract each of those 100 bookmarks to individual files that would work too.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I think I just heard the forest out back of me wince in agony...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601844/split-a-pdf-by-bookmarks/78150757#78150757

Answer (score 0):

This [virtual printer driver](http://www.printandshare.info) can split pdf files and directly print them in duplex (double sided) in black&white or colour and/or 2 pages on one sheet if needed.
All you need to do is create a new Profile with a printer, set the output options to: "Every page in the document is a separate transmission" and configure its Options.
Next thing you do is add parameter recognition and split on the font size or font type that is used for the chapter, and you are done.

[image]

Comment: This is commercial software with a free trial.  Unfortunately, their web site offers no information on cost, and offers to hook you up with a dealer if you want cost or purchase information.  There's a free trial, but they offer no information on whether the trial version is limited in features, how long the trial is for, or what happens at the end of the trial.  The answer would be more useful if you could provide any of that information.

Comment: @fixer1234  The 30-day trial is corporate version. Trial version adds a watermark to the output of PDF. After 30 day it does not allow you to work with it anymore. I just contacted via the website and they helped me out. During my trial I bought a license and I received it and now using it.
Maybe you have a Ricoh shop near you where you can ask for more info (but this is a new product, I have not seen it in all stores yet)

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools for PDF Split and Merge by different means and each has different benefits or potential problems. However for this simple case of split a PDF into 100 parts of 10 pages for double sided (Duplex) printing, then PDFill as suggested uses Ghostscript which has that ability. You will need to consider that part as separate from splitting, because it is specific to each sites printers.

With PDFill the instruction in this case will be, simply confirm all 1000 pages need to be split into groups of 10, then apply a location and file name, here I used fred, and 100  files will be produced with source file contents.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

The free [PDFill PDF Tools](http://www.pdfill.com/pdf_tools_free.html) can split a pdf file, but you will need to execute the split manually 9 times to split into 10 parts.

Comment: @KJ: Why are you bothering to downvote an answer that's from 12 years ago?